# Нужно Сериализировать одну переменную в Python

Tags: python-3.x, переменные, сериализация

есть у меня переменная i = True
И в коде при выполнении условия True заменяется на False и мне надо сохранить это значение переменной i, но не через dill т. к. он сохраняет все переменные, а мне нужно только одна, но если вы знаете как через dill сохранить только одну переменную, то пишите

Пример с библиотекой dill на фото

Заранее спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте код как текст в вопрос вставить с форматированием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сохраняем:

```
import pickle

i = False
with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(i, f)
```

загружаем:

```
with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    i = pickle.load(f)
```